# Windows Phone 8.1 open link in other app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a program which can show some links (music/video/ etc....).
I want when Clicked on download button, my app send that link to UC Downloader for download. I can open link with Internet Explorer but I want open in UC Downloader.

Answer (score 3):

You can launch an app from your code if you know. From the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) :

> By using the association launching API, your app can automatically launch another app by launching a custom URI. To do this, use the Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(Uri) method from the Launcher object of the Windows.System namespace. For example, the following code launches a fictitious Contoso app to display new products.

Example :

```
private async void LaunchContosoNewProductsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs rea)
{
    // Launch URI.
    Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("contoso:NewProducts"));
}
```

You can find a [tutorial here](http://www.developer.com/ws/creating-auto-launch-windows-phone-8-application-using-file-and-uri-associations.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how.

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("uc-url:http://www.microsoft.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.bing.com";
    var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
    var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);              
}
```

In windows phone 8.1